# ShareKit for the Web?

Tags: share

I was wondering if anyone knows of something similar to [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/) for web development?  It's a great plugin for iPhone apps that lets you easily share content.  It would be great if something similar made sharing as easy within webapps.

Ideally I'd be looking for something that's javascript and ruby based.

Answer (score 1):

[ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-button) is along the same lines as far as I can see, although I haven't implemented it yet.